# how to decode h264 data from rtsp stream directively to BGR24 pixel format for cv::Mat or cv::cuda::GpuMat with ffmpeg c lib on NVIDIA GPU?

Tags: ffmpeg, nvidia, codec

I want decode h264 dirctively to cv::Mat or cv::cuda::GpuMat without sws_scale to saving CPUs.

So is there any way to make it realized? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If the video is encoded as YUV, it must be converted using something like swscale. There is not “directly” decode to a format other than the one it was encoded as.